# jquery mobile 1.3 grid "ui-block-b" like ABB not ABC

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have 2 item, It's should be `33% width` and `66% width`. So I try to find this grid in `jquery mobile 1.3.2`.

But I just find the grid "**ui-block-b**" have `A(33%), B(33%), C(33%` 3 item, How can I use `A(33%), BB(66%)` item in jquery mobile framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ui-grid-a` and override `ui-block-a` & `ui-block-b` width.

HTML

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>

  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ui-block-a {
  width: 33% !important;
}

.ui-block-b {
  width: 66% !important;
}
```